# bash: /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash: No such file or directory

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when ever I open a new terminal this message appears on the top every time
" bash: /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash: No such file or directory "

I'me working on ROS INDIGO and it's working pretty fine.. Yet I've no concern with ros kinetic so this message annoys me!
Please help me if I can get rid of this..!!

Thanks :-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253480/bash:-/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [md.hussain](https://answers.ros.org/users/29222/md.hussain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-02-01

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ranjii28](https://answers.ros.org/users/41835/ranjii28/) on 2019-05-25**:
bash: /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash: No such file or directory
so am the beginer of ROS i am trying to install ROS but i am continuesly finding this error even though i had deleted the route line in the directory so please provide a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably have a `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` line somewhere in your `.bashrc` (assuming you use bash as your shell).

Open `$HOME/.bashrc`, remove the line, save.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [md.hussain](https://answers.ros.org/users/29222/md.hussain/) on 2017-02-01**:
Thank you so much :-)
Problem Solved..

**Comment by [aashrayjain](https://answers.ros.org/users/30426/aashrayjain/) on 2017-05-17**:
I've installed ROS INDIGO and got the same error.
Tried your solution too.
But "HOME/.bashrc" command isn't working either.
gives the following error
bash: HOME/.bashrc: No such file or directory

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-17**:
It's `$HOME`, not `HOME` (note the dollar sign).

But in any case: Indigo and Kinetic don't install on the same system, so I'm curious to know what you have done exactly?

**Comment by [mallikarjun.talagade](https://answers.ros.org/users/31025/mallikarjun.talagade/) on 2017-07-05**:
Thank you very much. Problem Solved.

Basically go to home directory then press ctrl+h then you can see hidden files then search for .bashrc and remove the lines.

**Comment by [Dinesh151](https://answers.ros.org/users/31215/dinesh151/) on 2017-07-16**:
thanks, bro. It worked.

**Comment by [AnirudhTopiwala](https://answers.ros.org/users/31737/anirudhtopiwala/) on 2017-08-29**:
i tried the same, but its showing Permission Denied. Please help

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-30**:
@AnirudhTopiwala: your problem is most likely more a Linux problem than a ROS problem. But "permission denied" errors seem to suggest you are trying to edit another user's `.bashrc`. You probably don't have permission to do that.

**Comment by [ercan_ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/33033/ercan_ros/) on 2017-12-26**:
Dear Users, I had a very similar problem, `$HOME` gave error. I found out this and it fixed the problem: execute `gedit ~/.bashrc`. On bottom in file, there is `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` . Just delete that code and save. (note: the ROS distro might differ in your case). reopen terminal.

**Comment by [dlrlr](https://answers.ros.org/users/35424/dlrlr/) on 2018-05-23**:
I got the same error, I tried to use `gedit ~/.bashrc`, after I see the file empty. Currently, I installed the Melodic ubuntu17.

**Comment by [shaswat.dharaiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/39199/shaswat.dharaiya/) on 2018-12-26**:
Worked just fine, thnq.!

**Comment by [nullspace](https://answers.ros.org/users/57539/nullspace/) on 2020-08-11**:
how will you delete the line i am unable to delete it
my steps
* vi /.bashrc
* at end of line i could find "source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash" along with "export DISPLAY" 5 times since i faced the error so reinstalled 5 times but could not solve the problem

**Comment by [nullspace](https://answers.ros.org/users/57539/nullspace/) on 2020-08-11**:
sorry it vi .bashrc